# Unity Particle System How to rotate particle effect?

Tags: rotation, particles

[image]

My Particle System creates a "puff" of smoke.
When I rotate the particle system it doesn't rotate the effect, just the way the particle is shot.
[image]

What I want to do is when I shoot a wall have it "puff" horizontal not vertical. And vertical when hitting floor. I want it to follow the normals of the surface I am raycasting to.

My problem is that the texture doesn't turn with it's parent rotation.
[image]

Do I need to write my own Custom Simulation Space to be able to rotate the effect?
Assigning the transform of the parent does nothing.

Prefab structure:
[image]

Particle Settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want to draw this as a mesh, not a billboard.

Comment: Seems to be the only option.